# Assign week numbers based on date ranges from another Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to add a Week # Column to df1. I want to assign week numbers based on date ranges found in df2.

```
df1 

WorkDate 

2022-05-03

2022-05-16

2022-05-24
```

```
df2 

Week #       Week Start        Week End

1            2022-05-01         2022-05-07
2            2022-05-08         2022-05-14
3            2022-05-15         2022-05-21
4            2022-05-22         2022-05-28
5            2022-05-29         2022-06-04
```

Expected Results

```
final_df 

WorkDate         Week #
 
2022-05-03         1
 
2022-05-16         3

2022-05-24         4
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) (*Note*: the dataframes must be sorted):

```py
df1["WorkDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["WorkDate"])
df2["Week Start"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Week Start"])

x = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on="WorkDate", right_on="Week Start")
print(x[["WorkDate", "Week #"]])
```

Prints:

```
    WorkDate  Week #
0 2022-05-03       1
1 2022-05-16       3
2 2022-05-24       4
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is with [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df1["WorkDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["WorkDate"])
df2["Week Start"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Week Start"])
df2['Week End'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Week End'])

(df1
.conditional_join(
    df2, 
    ('WorkDate', 'Week Start', '>='), 
    ('WorkDate', 'Week End', '<='))
)
    WorkDate  Week # Week Start   Week End
0 2022-05-03       1 2022-05-01 2022-05-07
1 2022-05-16       3 2022-05-15 2022-05-21
2 2022-05-24       4 2022-05-22 2022-05-28
```